# Ansible extract value using regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a file similar to below.

```
SITE "A" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,state:Stopped)
SITE "B" (id:2,bindings:https/*:344:,net.tcp/325:*,net.pipe/*,state:Started)
SITE "C" (id:3,bindings:http/:80:xyz.domain.com,http/*:80:xyz,http/*:80:seiging,http/*:80:seiging.domain.com,state:Started)
SITE "D" (id:4,bindings:http/:901:,http/*:80:actdaov,state:Started)
SITE "E" (id:5,bindings:https/:443:idu.domain.com,http/*:80:idu.domain.com,state:Started)
```

I want to extract the below content.

> "A,id:1,",
>   "B,id:2,",
>   "C,id:3,http/*:80:seiging.domain.com",
>
>   "D,id:4,",
>
>   "E,id:5,http/*:80:idu.domain.com",

The third field - If domain.com is present I need to extract that, if not it should be blank. If more than one domain.com exists then I need to take the last one.

I tried as below:

```
set_fact: inv_op="{{  item | regex_replace('SITE \\\"(.*)\\\" \((.*)\,bindings(.*)\,state.*', '\\1,\\2,\\3')  }}"
```

Output as below:

> "A,id:1,:http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*",
>
>   "B,id:2,:https/*:344:,net.tcp/325:*,net.pipe/*",
>   "C,id:3,:http/:80:xyz.domain.com,http/*:80:xyz,http/*:80:seiging,http/*:80:seiging.domain.com",
>
>   "D,id:4,:http/:901:,http/*:80:actdaov",
>   "E,id:5,:https/:443:idu.domain.com,http/*:80:idu.domain.com",

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create a dictionary first. For example the tasks

```
- set_fact:
    my_lines: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.csv').splitlines() }}"
- set_fact:
    my_lists: "{{ my_lists|default([]) + [item.split(' ')] }}"
  loop: "{{ my_lines }}"
- set_fact:
    my_dict: "{{ my_dict|default({})|
                 combine({item.1.1: {'id': item.2.split(',')[0].split(':')[1],
                                     'state': item.2.split(',')[-1].split(':')[1][:-1],
                                     'bindings': item.2.split(',')[1:-1]|
                                      map('regex_replace', 'bindings:', '')|list}})
                                      }}"
  loop: "{{ my_lists }}"
```

give

```
"my_dict": {
    "A": {
        "bindings": [
            "http/*:80:", 
            "net.tcp/808:*", 
            "net.pipe/*"
        ], 
        "id": "1", 
        "state": "Stopped"
    }, 
    "B": {
        "bindings": [
            "https/*:344:", 
            "net.tcp/325:*", 
            "net.pipe/*"
        ], 
        "id": "2", 
        "state": "Started"
    }, 
    "C": {
        "bindings": [
            "http/:80:xyz.domain.com", 
            "http/*:80:xyz", 
            "http/*:80:seiging", 
            "http/*:80:seiging.domain.com"
        ], 
        "id": "3", 
        "state": "Started"
    }, 
    "D": {
        "bindings": [
            "http/:901:", 
            "http/*:80:actdaov"
        ], 
        "id": "4", 
        "state": "Started"
    }, 
    "E": {
        "bindings": [
            "https/:443:idu.domain.com", 
            "http/*:80:idu.domain.com"
        ], 
        "id": "5", 
        "state": "Started"
    }
}
```

Then print the data. For example the task

> *"The third field - If domain.com is present I need to extract that, if not it should be blank. If more than one domain.com exists then I need to take the last one."*

```
- debug:
    msg: |
      {{ item.key }},id:{{ item.value.id }},
      {%- if item.value.bindings|select('search', 'domain\.com')|list %}
      {{ item.value.bindings|select('search', 'domain\.com')|reverse|list|first }},
      {% endif %}
  loop: "{{ my_dict|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "A,id:1,\n"
"msg": "C,id:3,http/*:80:seiging.domain.com,\n"
"msg": "B,id:2,\n"
"msg": "E,id:5,http/*:80:idu.domain.com,\n"
"msg": "D,id:4,\n"
```

Comment: In the third set_fact:  my_dict, what is item, I could not see any loop. I get error 'item' is undefined

Comment: Right. I've fixed the loop. Thank you.

Comment: I also tried with ansible as below, the regex is actually working in regex tool, but not in ansible. It doesnt show error, but it doesn't extract the url as well.
Could you please let me know what is wrong here?
 set_fact: inv_op="{{  item | regex_replace('^SITE \\\"(.*)\\\" \((.*)\,bindings:(.*):(\b\w*\b)\.domain\.com\,(.*)state(.*)', '\\1,\\2,\\4')  }}"

Comment: It's triple-expansion 1. Ansible "{{ 2. function( 3. regex. Sure it's possible, but why? Sorry, I'm not going to test it. [Keep it simple, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and put the *regex/replace* into separate variables. See [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-135/test2.yml).